# read elements file txt bash

Tags: bash, line

I have a file text titled test.txt containing

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4
1 12 2 4 5 66
```

I would like to read it line by line and for each line I would like to extract the elements.

I tried with

```
while read lines; 
do 

  echo $lines

done < test.txt
```

It prints correctly the lines of the matrix saved in the txt file but now I don't know how extract the single elements from the variable lines...

I would like to do something like this

```
while read lines; 
do 

 ((for i = 0; i<=numberofelementline; i++))
 do 
   element = ....
   echo $element

 done

done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    read -a line <<< $a
    for i in ${!line[@]}; do echo ${rline[i]}; done
```

We read a file / line and store as an array. Next for each element of the array we run a for loop. This way you know the element and it's position.

Comment: To be a really useful answer, provide some commentary about what the really important bits are (`-a`, `${!...`), and demonstrate how to read the lines from a file

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all spaces to new lines and read them again with another `while` loop:

```
while read LINE; do
        echo "$LINE"  | tr -s ' ' '\n' | while read NUM; do
                echo $NUM
        done
done < test.txt
```

Comment: If I put element=$NUM in the variable element I still get the content of all the line...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to echo them:

```
cat test.txt | tr ' ' '\n'
```

If you want to use the numbers:

```
while read num; do
    echo $num
    ...
done < <( cat test.txt | tr ' ' '\n' )
```